# pop up panel from codebehind on button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, popup, code-behind

I have asp.net web application in which generate a button dynamically and I want to open pop up page or panel on that button click event.

I try the following code but it doesn't work:

```
protected void Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

   OpenNewWindow("test.aspx");
}

public void OpenNewWindow(string url)

{
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "newWindow", String.Format("<script>window.open('{0}');</script>", url));

}
```

Comment: It should work. It could be you have a javascript error in your page and the script is not getting executed, as the execution is terminating somewhere else. Also, check that your pop-up blocker isn't blocking the site.

Comment: TBH : why perform a Postback to the server when you could accomplish the same interaction using Javascript anyway?  Secondly (and this is untested) but does the 'RegisterStartupScript' work for Postbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Add attribute to the dynamically created buttons

```
Button1.Attributes.Add( "onclick", "javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com');" );
```